# Strange redirection with htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, netcat

In my .htaccess I have this lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^test.ru [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.ru/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

so I want to change test.ru to www.test.ru

and also to give www.test.ru/my_string_value/ to $_GET['string']

(for example from this URL www.test.ru/ru/pages/id/) , exploding this ru/pages/888 , getting my parameters (lang=ru, cat=pages, id=888).

When I'm trying to check www adding part (writing test.ru must make www.test.ru) geting this:

http://www.test.ru/index.php?string=http://www.test.ru

With parameters getting is ok!

And one interesting thing! After comenting lines

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{http_host} ^test.ru [nc]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.ru/$1 [r=301,nc]
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

getting the same thing!

What is wrong.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the same problem (the commented lines I realized that the browser is saving redirect caches): But I am getting the variables in the new URL too, why is this happening?

Comment: Found the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048311/htaccess-redirect-with-url-friendly-mod-rewrite
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have some things in the wrong order but you are probably cached.  The browser will cache 301 redirects. Clear your browser cache or try in another browser. Also use 302 while testing. Then change to 301 when everything is working. And you should use the `L` flag on redirects as well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.ru/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not working geting string part. So for example: http://www.test1.ru/ru/smtng/  geting index.php as $_GET['string'] . And in local server works but in real , still no.

Comment: When removing ? works in local server, but not in real (may be hoster broblem?)     like this:                                                            RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.ru/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: Are you putting this in the .htaccess file or apache config? The `?` only makes the the `/` optional when browsing the URL. Are you using a URL with a `/` at the end?

Comment: Also the rule is supposed to give the string part. All it's doing is adding `www` to the domain but forwarding the URI that you requested as well. so `tes1.ru/ru/smtg` becomes `www.test1.ru/ru/smtg`. It's supposed to do that how it's written now. Then your other rule will pick it up and send to `string=`

Comment: yes im doing test1.ru/ru/smtng/ (this editor removes last slash). Writing all in .htaccess file.

Comment: So what exactly is happening then? When you type in your domain, what happens exactly on the `real` server?