# .htaccess redirect with URL friendly (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using `RewriteRule` in my URLs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now I need to create a 301 redirect. So I do that:

```
Redirect 301 /port/reestruturacao-financeira http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa/
```

The result is wrong:

http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa//?lang=port&page=reestruturacao-financeira

How can I fix that? redirect

http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa/

to

http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa/

Comment: Does this url 


https://www.website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa/ exits?

Comment: @starkeen Yes. It's exist.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: @starkeen Nope. Just that.

Comment: @starkeen Sorry. Found a rule to remove www: RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep redirect `301` rule before other internal rewrite rule and use only `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^port/reestruturacao-financeira /port/reestruturacao-corporativa/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing.